# Alternate solution to avoid "Refused to display to 'SAMEORIGIN' www.google.co.in/maps/place/"

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have a requirement to display the Google map on profile page of user and Google Map URL will be added by the end user. For this user can search for the location on Google and can copy Google map URL which is provided by Google as results. This is the easiest way for the end user for get the Google map URL.

While displaying the Google Map URL in `iframe`, I am getting following error:

Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Prince+Bijoy+Memorial+Hospital/@28.012196,73.326442,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x9e25cc2a3dc80115&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

**Here is the sample URL:**

https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Prince+Bijoy+Memorial+Hospital/@28.012196,73.326442,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x9e25cc2a3dc80115

My `iframe` :

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Prince+Bijoy+Memorial+Hospital/@28.012196,73.326442,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x9e25cc2a3dc80115" height="800" width="800"></iframe>
```

**Note**: 
I searched on web regarding the issue but did not find any solution that provide an easy way to generate the Google map URL.

Please share suggestions.

Comment: @geocodezip it is not a duplicate .. we already shared that we searched on web and tried all the suggestions .. and now we are asking for alternate solution .. please suggest .. thnx

Comment: That answer basically says "it won't work unless you convince google to change their configuration" (not likely) or you don't put it in an iframe.  You are saying you saw that answer and it didn't work for you?

Comment: see .. we know that iframe will not work with our URL .. because of "SAMEORIGIN" .. this is an urgent task and we do not have much time to communicate with or convince any body .. that is why we are asking for an alternate solution ...all we want is an easy way for our user to display Google Map. Please suggest if you have any alternate in your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow below link.

http://www.wikihow.com/Geocode-an-Address-in-Google-Maps-Javascript

It will overcome your issue.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use embedding api https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3544418?hl=en.
Just click on cog in the left bottom corner on the map, then 'Share and embed map', then 'Iframe'.

Comment: thanks for reply, I will discuss with my seniors regarding your suggestion and will let you know the results .. :)

Comment: You can read more about it here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: thanks again .. I am new with this Google map thing so may be I sound stupid asking this but before proceeding with your suggestion I need to confirm one thing .. as we have mentioned in our question that we need the end user to enter the URL and then the Google map will display on the web page .. so please confirm if this suggestion will work in our case or not and what can be the UI process for the end user?

Comment: User should also get url in the same way, via 'Iframe' tab in 'Share and embed map'. Seems like you can't transform any gmap link into link for embedding yourself.