# google map Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps

am trying to add an iframe map at this location:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/32.2221546+35.2965266/@32.2221546,35.2965266,17z
```

like

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/32.2221546+35.2965266/@32.2221546,35.2965266,17z"></iframe>
```

but I get an error, somebody can help me

Comment: You should at least share the error message you are facing. It would be even better to share the attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: The error I get with the `<iframe>` in your question is: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`.

Comment: possible duplicate/related question: [Embedding youtube video "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934944/embedding-youtube-video-refused-to-display-document-because-display-forbidden-b)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternate solution to avoid "Refused to display to 'SAMEORIGIN' www.google.co.in/maps/place/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485968/alternate-solution-to-avoid-refused-to-display-to-sameorigin-www-google-co-in)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps not working in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000561/google-maps-not-working-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Open the original link (to Google Maps), click on "share", then "Embed a map", "Copy HTML" will give you the `<iframe>` to include on your page.

Comment: thank you it work done

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The location code you typed is a google map format. You should use this code when you need to share directly.(for example on WhatsApp, an e-mail)

Try this instead. when you copied the location code to browser, you will see the sharing settings. There is information enough on that page.

I found out your location on this page and saw following code.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3375.3346517032583!2d35.2965266!3d32.2221546!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x24759be185862de8!2zMzLCsDEzJzE5LjgiTiAzNcKwMTcnNDcuNSJF!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1643914372999!5m2!1str!2str" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

[explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DAbU.jpg)

Comment: it's work done, How you use this location, can you tell me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).